# Fluent NHibernate Dictionary Mapping

Tags: vb.net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I'm attempting to create an IDictionary on an object using another class as the key.

```
' Dictionary Mapping on Tool
    HasMany(Function(x) x.Roles).KeyColumn("ToolRole_ID").AsEntityMap("RoleType_ID").Inverse.Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().Table("ToolRoles")

' RoleType Mapping
Public Sub New()
    Id(Function(x) x.ID).GeneratedBy.GuidComb().Column("ToolRole_ID")
    References(Function(x) x.Tool).Not.Nullable.Column("Tool_ID")
    References(Function(x) x.RoleType).Not.Nullable.Column("RoleType_ID")
    References(Function(x) x.User).Not.Nullable.Column("User_ID")
    Map(Function(x) x.LastModified).Not.Nullable()
    Table("ToolRoles")
End Sub
```

I no longer get any mapping errors thanks to this post: [How to map this Dictionary with the newest fluentNHibernate version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443907/how-to-map-this-dictionary-with-the-newest-fluentnhibernate-version) , but my collection is not being populated even though I know it has child objects.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because RoleType is a Property of ToolRole you could try the standard Map syntax.

```
HasMany(Function(x) x.Roles)
    .KeyColumn("ToolRole_ID")
    .AsMap(Function(x) x.RoleType)
    .Inverse()
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I tried this once, but to be sure I did it again and I get the following error: `{"Could not determine type for: ToolDatabaseLib.RoleType, ToolDatabaseLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(RoleType)"}`

Comment: then enable sql logging in NHibernate and run the generated sql of your mapping directly to see if it returns the results you expect.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed acceptance on this. The original reason for asking this question actually went away so I didn't have the code to work with anymore. I just did another dictionary mapping and it worked fine. One note is with `AsMap` you should not use a lambda function to specify the property you want to expose if the column name of the property does not match the property name. My working mapping was `.AsMap(of String)("task_name")` instead of `.AsMap(function(x) x.Name))`